# Rails Redirect 301 encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have recreated a website and have lots of 301 to handle (from php urls to Rails urls).

It works perfectly with :

```
match "/produits/les-dallages/dallage-riva.html", :to => redirect("/produits/dallages/dalle-riva")
```

My problem is for this kind of old urls (providing from google webmaster tools):

```
"/produits/les-pavages/paves-carres/item/48-pav%C3%A9s-carr%C3%A9s.html"
```

The encoding is not understood because the url is transformed by the browser and Rails didn't understand the url with "é" instead of "%C3%A9"...

How to manage this kind of urls ?

Second question: how many routes (301) can I add in the routes.rb file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you could add many routes you want. However, we should not put unnecessary in the routes file because it would eat up memory, and it needs to some times to process all the routes logic for every request before it can go to the controller.

In case you have quite a lot of urls to do redirection, rather than mess up with routes file, I would recommend you create a controller just to do redirection, because you could write a lot more flexible code. Maybe you could create a table to store `from_url` (old url) and `new_url` (for redirection). Then, inside a new controller, simply find the old url in the database and do a redirect.

```
class RedirectionController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect = Redirection.find_by_from_url(request.request_uri)
    if redirect
      redirect_to redirect.to_url, :status => :moved_permanently
    else
      render 'public/404', :status => :not_found, :layout => false
    end
  end
end
```

Last, use **Route Globbing** to match any urls for redirection. You can check out more about it on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

```
match '/produits/*' => 'redirection#index'
```

For accent characters like 'é', you simply need to store this value inside your database. For MySQL, you should configure your database server to store `utf-8` and update the connection inside database.yml.

```
encoding: utf8
collation: utf8_unicode_ci
```

You can try to redirect by the following code. It works perfectly okay. It must have `# encoding: UTF-8` at the beginning of the file because there are those accent characters.

```
# encoding: UTF-8
class RedirectionController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to "produits/les-pavages/paves-carres/item/48-pavés-carrés"
  end
end
```